# How to fix "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.pipeline() is applicable "

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is driving me crazy :(
I had a large script with `matrix` and other impressive commands (newbie here!) - and it wouldn't work. And even after cutting it down to a minimalized repro, I get the same error...and have no idea what's wrong. Other cases that I saw here were due to using wrong number or arguments when calling methods etc., but I don't see how I could be doing that here.

```
    pipeline {
      agent none
      stages {
                stage ('GetPath') {
                    agent{
                      label 'mac'
                    }
                    steps {                
                        sh'echo "hello world"'
                      }
                    }
                }
              }
```

### Result

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.pipeline() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@7fc0098d]
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:585)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:623)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:594)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:142)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:114)
at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:46)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:111)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4558)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4529)
at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:627)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:396)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:408)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:212)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:145)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:536)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:766)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:898)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:694)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:76)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:151)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:153)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:92)
at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:92)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:93)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:62)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:97)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:109)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:51)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:36)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:279)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: This looks a lot like a misconfiguration of plugins on the master. Is the Jenkins Pipeline plugin installed?

Comment: Hmm, to be honest: no idea, but I think so - have asked the IT to have a look. (I'm just a poor developer....)    ;)

Comment: They did confirm it was ok and they were using pipeline on at least 50% of the Jenkins jobs.

Comment: The error claims there is no definition for a `pipeline` method with a `closure` argument, so the plugin is either not installed (i.e. you are using declarative and only scripted may be installed), misconfigured, you do not have permission to use it, or this pipeline code is not executing as a pipeline but rather as a generic groovy script. The code itself is completely valid.

Comment: Ah, that was it! My bad :((   If you wanna post this as an answer, I'll accept and will close the case. Hoping to come back with "real" problems instead of self-made ;)

Comment: What ended up being the solution for you?

Comment: Not executing scripted pipeline in the groovy-script window ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.pipeline() is applicable for argument types: (Script1$_run_closure1)

indicates that there is an undefined reference to a `pipeline` method with a `Closure` type argument. This is the correct argument type for the `pipeline` method, so this becomes an error related to the method being undefined rather than incorrect usage.

The method could be resolved as undefined during pre-execution for any or all of the following reasons:

- The Jenkins Pipeline plugin is not installed
- Only the scripted pipeline plugin is installed and you are using the declarative DSL
- The plugin(s) is misconfigured
- Your user does not have permission to leverage the plugin
- The pipeline code is executing as a generic groovy script instead of as pipeline code (ergo the pipeline groovy methods would not be automatically loaded as invocable references, and would need to be explicitly imported instead)