# Jenkins triggerRemoteJob MissingMethodException

Tags: jenkins

This plugin was installed https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger

and the function can be found in Snippet Generator

[image]

run the generated snippet in the script console:

```
def handle = triggerRemoteJob job: 'THE_JOB', parameters: "A=B", remoteJenkinsName: 'THE_REMOTE_SERVER_CONFIGURED', token: 'THE_TOKEN', useCrumbCache: true, useJobInfoCache: true
```

but resulted in following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.triggerRemoteJob() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[job:THE_JOB, parameters:A=B, remoteJenkinsName:THE_SERVER_CONFIGURED, ...]]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:169)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:1)
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Not the same problem you are having but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68532292/3730626) gives a number of possible reasons why this can happen.